# Setting existing value as default in Select dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down which contains the following values

```
<select class="form-control">
<option value="critical">Critical</option>
<option value="high">High</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="low">Low</option>
</select>
```

Because of this in drop-down the value is always selected to "Critical"

In my scope i have defined the values of severity per drop-down. How do i select that ?

For example say the value is "High". How do i set the default value to high and not critical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define at object within your scope and bind it to the `ng-model` of your select.

**Script**

```
$scope.form = {
    "severity": "high"
};
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="form.severity">
    <option value="critical">Critical</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="low">Low</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to select an option with angular:

**1-** Bind it to a model and set the model:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="myValue">
```

And

```
$scope.myValue = 'medium';
```

**2-** You can set it in a directive by jQuery or JS:

```
$("#yourselectid").val('low');
```